# Why does my main Bibtex bibliography contain so many duplicates?

Tags: bibtex

I understand that if one merges bibliographies one is liable to create duplicate entries. I have one main bibliography that I have never merged with any others, and yet it has recently acquired very numerous duplicate entries with identical cite keys.

How has this happened? What can I do about it?

Comment: Please clarify the process by which “[the main bib file] has recently acquired very numerous duplicates”.

Comment: @Mico I cannot clarify the process because that is precisely what my question is: what is the process. If you mean what are the symptoms of my trouble then they are that almost without exception every entry in my bibliography is now duplicated.

Comment: I am using Bibdesk Version 1.6.21 (4769) on a Mac running Mojave 10.14.3. I do not edit my bib file, or do anything to the file;  I just add entries to it and when I render documents (using TexShop Version 4.01) that contain citations then that program presumably reads the bib file behind the scenes to gather the required info.

Comment: It might be that Bibdesk automatically added these entries, but that is not very likely. If your file is somehow synchronized (using Dropbox or Owncloud or something) then there may be an issue with that. Or you may have accidentally done something yourself (in Bibdesk or elsewhere) that copied the entries. In any case, you could try removing the duplicates, watch closely to see if it happens again, and if it does, try to remember or trace any activity with the file to find the cause of the issue.